# Configuring org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions in SAML to implement XACML

Tags: spring, security, binding, saml, xacml

I am new in spring security, I have been trying to implement XACML along with SAML, so far i was able to implement SSO with OpenAM, now i need the same application to have authorization module.

*So far I got to know that the webSSOProfileOptions which will help me to configure my authrequest which i need to send by SOAP binding over HTTP,
I have been reading this pdf* https://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/2.0/access_control-xacml-2.0-saml-profile-spec-os.pdf *for reference which has mentioned about the bindings which i need to use.*

if this is the auth-request for simple SAML

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
             AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://sp.com/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias"
             Destination="https://idp.com/idp"
             ForceAuthn="false"
             ID="a4acj06d42fdc0d3494h859g3f7005c"
             IsPassive="false"
             IssueInstant="2012-12-05T17:07:18.271Z"
             ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
             Version="2.0"
             >
```

I want this to be encoded into SOAP and be able to send it via URL. Till now I had been using the default request.

But I am having doubt about the attributes of XACML which i have to include in the message. If this is the way then where and how do i have to send the request. Please fill me out here, as I am unable to understand on how would i send my customized message in the SOAP.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which XACML PDP are you using? The way you send the request depends on the PDP.

Comment: @DavidBrossard I am using wso2 as my pdp